# Using sqlalchemy to connect to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using a Windows 10 machine with a local installation of Postgres which I am trying to access using Python.

I am getting an error that the database called 'mydatabase' as per code below does not exist. The actual message is "psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "mydatabase" does not exist."

from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, Numeric, String,
                         DateTime, ForeignKey, create_engine)

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:helpdeskNo1@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

Comment: What is unclear about the error?

Comment: My understanding of an ORM like sqlalchemy, is that it allows one  to define classes in code which it then translates to the relevant database engine. In this case I have defined classes and I am thus expecting the ORM to issue SQL statements to the database engine and thus create the database.

Comment: ORMs will often be able to create the *tables* for you but they usually expect the *database* to exist. Just use a tool like [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/) to create the database and then proceed from there.